# CUDPP faster than THRUST in sorting? so what about structure arrays?

Tags: cuda, thrust, cudpp

I have an array of structures and I want to sort them. I have been using Thrust::sort and it works well. Then people tell me CUDPP is faster in sorting but I found it's not possible to sort structure arrays straight forward.

[Here](http://choorucode.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/cudpp-sorting-a-structure-array/) they have explained how to sort structure arrays with CUDPP but it sounds resource consuming.

Do you have any suggestion on faster doing the sort? Any other way you do this job?

P.S. my structure is simply some numbers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to do the timings yourself for your specific architecture / configuration.

Once you provide the results and the code of the two implementations then SO can help spot some
performance improvements.